# How can I load back from a text file the values to the variables?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm using a simple text file to write to using StreamWriter but maybe it's better to use a json. For example how I used the json before:

```
Transform[] trnfrm = new Transform[tranformToSave.Length];
string jsonTransform = JsonHelper.ToJson(trnfrm, true);
File.WriteAllText(@"d:\json\json.txt", jsonTransform);
```

But now I'm using a text file and not sure how to use the json(for saving/loading) if it's better and how to read back from the text file and assign back:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Conversation> conversations = new List<Conversation>();

    [HideInInspector]
    public int dialogueNum = 0;

    [HideInInspector]
    public int dialogueIndex = 0;

    private bool triggered = false;
    private List<Dialogue> oldDialogue;
    private bool activateButton = false;

    public void TriggerDialogue(int dialogueIndex)
    {
        this.dialogueIndex = dialogueIndex;

        if (conversations.Count > 0 &&
            conversations[dialogueIndex].Dialogues.Count > 0)
        {
            if (triggered == false)
            {
                if (FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>() != null)
                {
                    FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(conversations[dialogueIndex].Dialogues[dialogueNum]);
                    dialogueNum += 1;
                }
                triggered = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        ButtonActivation();

        if (DialogueManager.dialogueEnded == true)
        {
            if (dialogueNum == conversations[dialogueIndex].Dialogues.Count)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(conversations[dialogueIndex].Dialogues[dialogueNum]);
                DialogueManager.dialogueEnded = false;
                dialogueNum += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool ActivateButton()
    {
        return activateButton;
    }

    private void ButtonActivation()
    {
        if (ConversationsChecks() == true)
        {
            foreach (string sentence in conversations[dialogueIndex].Dialogues[dialogueNum].sentences)
            {
                if (sentence != "")
                {
                    activateButton = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    activateButton = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            activateButton = false;
        }
    }

    public void SaveConversations()
    {
        StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"D:\conversation.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < conversations.Count; i++)
        {
            w.WriteLine("Conversation Name " + conversations[i].name);

            for (int x = 0; x < conversations[i].Dialogues.Count; x++)
            {
                w.WriteLine("Dialogue Name " + conversations[i].Dialogues[x].name);

                foreach (string sentence in conversations[i].Dialogues[x].sentences)
                {
                    w.WriteLine("Dialogue Sentences " + sentence);
                }
            }

            if (i != conversations.Count - 1)
                w.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        w.Close();
    }

    public void LoadConversations()
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\conversation.txt");


    }

    private bool ConversationsChecks()
    {
        bool IsConversationsReady = false;

        if (conversations.Count > 0 &&
            conversations[dialogueIndex].Dialogues.Count > 0 &&
            conversations[dialogueIndex].Dialogues[dialogueNum].sentences.Count > 0 &&
            conversations[dialogueIndex].Dialogues[dialogueNum].name != "" &&
            conversations[dialogueIndex].name != "")
        {
            IsConversationsReady = true;
        }
        else
        {
            IsConversationsReady = false;
        }

        return IsConversationsReady;
    }
}
```

I added a new public method:

```
 public void LoadConversations()
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\conversation.txt");


        }
```

But I'm not sure how to assign it back to the conversations > name > dialogues > name > sentences

This is the class Conversation:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Conversation
{
    [Tooltip("Conversation Name")]
    public string name;

    public List<Dialogue> Dialogues = new List<Dialogue>();
}
```

This is the class Dialogue:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Dialogue
{
    [Tooltip("Dialogue Name")]
    public string name;

    [TextArea(1, 10)]
    public List<string> sentences = new List<string>();
}
```

And the editor script for the button/s now I'm using only the save button:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(DialogueTrigger))]
public class SaveConversationsButton : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        DialogueTrigger dialoguetrigger = (DialogueTrigger)target;

        if(dialoguetrigger.ActivateButton() == true)
        {
            GUI.enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.enabled = false;
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("Save Conversations"))
        {
            dialoguetrigger.SaveConversations();
        }
    }
}
```

But now I want to use the load button too.

This is example of how the text file format looks like after a saving:

```
Conversation Name Conversation 1
Dialogue Name Dialogue 1
Dialogue Sentences Hello World
Dialogue Sentences It's my time to make a magic


Conversation Name The openning scene
Dialogue Name NAVI
Dialogue Sentences Hello to you
Dialogue Sentences Lets hide quick
Dialogue Name PLAYER
Dialogue Sentences I'm the player now lets go
```

And this is a screenshot of how it looks like in the inspector in the editor and how it should looks like after loading:

[image: Inspector]

Comment: Json classes typically have two methods: serialize (the part you have) and deserialize. Unity has a built in `JsonUtility` that can do this for you, but is pretty basic. If you need something more powerful, I recommend Newtonsoft's Json Dot Net.

Comment: I used JsonHelper and it was easy to save it to a Json file: string jsonTransform = JsonHelper.ToJson(conversations.ToArray(), true);
        File.WriteAllText(@"d:\json.txt", jsonTransform); but now how do I read it back to the conversations List ? Inside another method I did: string jsonTransform = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\json.txt");
        var t = JsonHelper.FromJson<string>(jsonTransform); but var t is now string array and I need it to be assigned read back into the conversations List.

Comment: `FromJson` uses the same type of object as the thing you put in `ToJson`. If you convert a `Conversation` object to JSON then when you want to do the reverse, why would you read it back as a string?

Comment: @Draco18s The problem is that if I'm doing: conversations = JsonHelper.FromJson<List<Conversation>>(jsonTransform); I'm getting error on the right side Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Conversation>[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Conversation>' And the type of the conversations List I used to save is List<Conversation> but it give me the error.

Comment: Doesnt look like your text file is in json at all.. if you saved it as json, you'd be able to read back the json.

Comment: `conversations.ToArray()`: you aren't serializing a list, you're serializing an array.